# Adding two symbolic equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equations

I have two equations in Matlab, say

```
x^2+2*y=3,   
y^4=5*x+1
```

Here x,y are symbolic variables. What is the best way to add up these two equations, not manually of course ( if the LHS and RHS gets added up separately and stays in the same form, the better).

Comment: Show code, and what you have tried, and why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
syms x y
a1=x^2+2*y-3
a2=y^4-5*x-1
a=a1+a2
```

The result,

```
ans = x^2 - 5*x + y^4 + 2*y - 4
```